Running a query and export the results
I have a query that I need to run on a daily basis then the results of this query I want to save to a csv file and save it in a shared drive.
I'm not sure how to do the export of the file to a drive called F:\SN_Product_Code\
I have the following code so far:
DECLARE @rmt_file varchar(50)
SET @rmt_file = (SELECT  'MicroBOOST ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':',''),4) + ' All.csv')
DECLARE @data varchar(max)
SET @data = (
select eela.SerialNumber, si.Name , si.Manufacturer
--, sdrl.DespatchReceiptDate
from SOPOrderReturn o with (nolock) inner join SOPOrderReturnLine ol with (nolock) On o.soporderreturnid=ol.soporderreturnid
  inner join EurekaElmbridgeLineAdditional eela with (nolock) On eela.soporderreturnlineid = ol.soporderreturnlineid
  inner join SOPDespatchReceiptLine sdrl with (nolock) On sdrl.SOPOrderReturnLineID=ol.SOPOrderReturnLineID
  left outer join Stockitem si with (nolock) On si.Code=ol.ItemCode
where o.documentstatusid In (0,1,2) and o.DocumentTypeID=0 and ol.ItemCode In ('10-005999-000','10-006569-000') and eela.SerialNumber is not null

FOR XML PATH (''))

@31/12/2024
I now have the following code, but am now getting the error

Msg 214, Level 16, State 201, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1 [Batch
Start Line 0] Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type
'varchar'.

set nocount on
DECLARE @OutputFilePath varchar(max);
DECLARE @ExportSQL varchar(max);
DECLARE @rmt_file varchar(50);
DECLARE @data varchar(max);

SET @OutputFilePath = 'F:\SN_Product_Code\';
SET @rmt_file = (SELECT  'MicroBOOST_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':',''),4) + '.csv')
SET @data = 
'"(select eela.SerialNumber, si.Name 
from SOPOrderReturn o with (nolock) inner join SOPOrderReturnLine ol with (nolock) On o.soporderreturnid=ol.soporderreturnid
  inner join EurekaElmbridgeLineAdditional eela with (nolock) On eela.soporderreturnlineid = ol.soporderreturnlineid
  inner join SOPDespatchReceiptLine sdrl with (nolock) On sdrl.SOPOrderReturnLineID=ol.SOPOrderReturnLineID
  left outer join Stockitem si with (nolock) On si.Code=ol.ItemCode
where o.documentstatusid In (0,1,2) and o.DocumentTypeID=0 and ol.ItemCode In (''10-005999-000'',''10-006569-000'') and eela.SerialNumber is not null)"'


SET @ExportSQL = 'bcp ' + @data + ' queryout ' + @OutputFilePath + @rmt_file 

EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @ExportSQL


A sql job is probably the easiest way to tackle this. I have to ask why all the NOLOCK hints? Are you ok with getting the data mostly accurate most of the time? And are you ok with getting duplicate and/or missing rows randomly?

This question is similar to: How to automatically save sql query results to .csv file. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

SQL doesn't "export" files, it's a querying language. Do not abuse it to do file access. You need a tool that can run the query and export to a file, for example bcp.exe or sqlcmd.exe or a Powershell script using DbaTools.

Highly recommended reading: Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere Do you have a legimate reason for using it against every object?

please do not forget also about different ETL-tools. They are designed to handle such tasks

If you do not want to utilize external applications, and you have a full sql license, SSIS is the way to go.  You have the sql query itself, creating an SSIS package is straight forward and can generate the output you want, and depending on your network access, drop it in the location you desire.  There are myriad guides and tutorials for SSIS.

this might help you Export to .csv
